# Python module random has no attribute choices working on local server but not on live server

Tags: python, django, random

I have a script which selects a random number form available list at random.
I have been testing it on django's local server and it worked fine but when I moved it to a live server I keep getting this error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'choices'
```

Here's my code:

```
import random

class singlePull(TemplateView):
template_name = 'gacha/singlepull.html'

def randomStar(self):
    choice = [5,4,3]
    probability = [0.1, 0.2, 0.7]
    star = random.choices(choice, probability)
    return star


def post(self, request):
    result = self.randomStar()
    for key in result:
        character = Characters.objects.filter(stars=key).order_by('?')[:1]
        for obj in character:
            name = obj.name
            stars = obj.stars
            series = obj.series
            image = obj.image
    return JsonResponse({'name': name, 'stars': stars, 'series': series, 'image': image}, safe=False)
```

How come I keep getting this error? What could be wrong here?

Comment: Post a complete minimal example. You don't show the random import so I know something is missing.  Anyway, try `random.random.choices()`

Comment: You're never importing the `random` module; the code you've shown would never work.

Comment: Where's the relevant import?

Comment: Just add `import random`

Comment: Ensure you do not have a random.py file in the same folder.

Comment: A quick look at the docs shows "New in version 3.6" for `random.choices`. Post the local and remote Python versions in your question.

Comment: Ok, I edited the original post. I pasted the wrong import.

Comment: I just noticed this might be due to a different python version on live server. Gonna work on it now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`choices` is added in version 3.6. Presumably the live server uses an older version while you locally use 3.6.

See [random.choices documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html?highlight=choices#random.choices): "New in version 3.6"

Comment: This might be it, I just noticed the live server has python 3.5.2. I can't upgrade, can I?

Comment: I don't know a lot about Python on web servers, but if you're not administrator on that server I don't think there's a way for you to upgrade.

Comment: The server is managed by me so that's not a problem. No worries, I will google that. Cheers