# Attribute Error when trying to use numpy.random.choices in Google Colaboratory

Tags: python, numpy, google-colaboratory

I am trying to use numpy.random.choices() to generate some pseudo-random data but am getting the following error message:

```
AttributeError: module 'numpy.random' has no attribute 'choices'
```

The existing threads I can find suggest that this is a version issue: it looks like Python must be [version 3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48010337/python-module-random-has-no-attribute-choices-working-on-local-server-but-not-on/48010413) or higher, and there may be minimum version requirements with NumPy as well. But I am using Python 3.7.12 and NumPy 1.21.5 in my environment and still getting this error. I'm also working in a Google Colaboratory file right now, which may have something to do with the error, but I'm not sure what or why.

Comment: `np.random.choice`.  The base module `random` has `choice` and `choices`.  `np.random` only has one of them.  That link is about the base `random`, not numpy.

Comment: Ah, stupid mistake on my part. Thanks for the help